# Why GAE launched a second instance with Max Idle Instances set to 1

Tags: google-app-engine

I use Google Ap Engine with billing Status Enabled.
Idle Instances are set to : ( 1 – 1 )

[image]

And with only 2 clients on my service, sometimes I saw a second instance.
The trouble is that it's take 15s to launch the new instance (spring and co..).

[image]

80Mb of memory is to hight for one instance ?
Log for new instance : /_ah/warmup 200 14580ms 0kb
The second instance disappears after a few seconds.

Why with 3-4 requests, GAE run a second instance ?? The first one do nothing (almost) !

I tried to modify "Pending Latency" without success.

A solution ? :)

Thx

Comment: I think this behaviour is quite normal. Whenever requests come in, GAE launches idle instances to be able to serve upcoming requests efficiently. This is just to ensure that all clients get good performance. I think we can compare this behaviour to the way connection pooling in databases works. Also see [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#Setting_the_Number_of_Idle_Instances)

Comment: I agree with you Jan; but why in the dynamic one he has "1" Requests. It's the same behaviour I have but it makes no sense to me because at this point it is not anymore a warmup cycle but a real cycle the handle request. And the request handled has a big latency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've asked for exactly one idle instance. When serving a request, an instance is not idle. Therefore, App Engine spins up a new instance to maintain your requested number of idle instances.

Comment: Interesting ! But if the new one is an idle instance, why it takes a request ? (so have 15s response time). The trouble is that I didn't have a lot of trafic. So if I will set min idle instance to Automatic, I'm afraid that all my customer will have 15s latency for their first request :(

Comment: The request is the warmup request, which is specifically to avoid your users having to put up with the loading time.

Answer (score 1):

If the resident instance is deemed "too busy" to handle a request, App Engine will start another one.  Even with very low traffic, if the app is handling enough requests simultaneously, AE may decide it needs another instance to provide quality service.  You are correct that increasing pending latency will reduce the chance that another instance gets started, but you can't prohibit dynamic instances completely.

Also, do you have multithreading enabled?  If not, then the resident instance will be busy even if it's handling just one request.  If your code is threadsafe, you can enable multithreading and handle more simultaneous requests concurrently with the instance.

With very low traffic and a very small number of instances, App Engine doesn't have a lot of information to go on when deciding whether it needs a new instance.  You'll see better utilization and fewer spurious instances with more traffic.

Comment: Thx Dan. Yes I enabled multithreading. It's crazy that it works better with more traffic :) How GAE determines that a instance is "too busy" ? Use a F2 instance is a solution ?

Comment: I only feel qualified to give a fuzzy answer here.  There are interesting things AE could be doing to make good guesses about whether a given request would be handled adequately by an instance under a particular amount of load. But I'm not sure what AE actually does, and I would want the AE team to have the freedom to tune this heavily and not commit to just one strategy.

Comment: The main thing to note is that with dynamic instances, AE reserves the right to start up new instances.  If you really want to keep everything going to one server, you could use an addressable backend, at the expense of dynamic load management.  But I'm guessing you're actually asking about instance utilization: does the 2nd instance imply the 1st instance is maxed out or poorly utilized? The answer is, at a given moment it might have been, but that doesn't mean your app is under continuous load larger than one instance can typically handle.